Does the In-App Review popup when the user has already rated the app?
I am trying to implement In-App Review method in my app and this is how I implemented it until now:
fun Context.onReview() {
    val reviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
    val request = reviewManager.requestReviewFlow()
    request.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val reviewInfo = task.result
            val flow = reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(this as MainActivity, reviewInfo)
            flow.addOnCompleteListener { }
        }
    }
}

I tested and the dialog poped up only once. After that I couldn't open the dialog again.
I just want to find out if the implementation is good enough and dialog pops up when the user has already rated the app. Because I can't find any function or return value for that within the task or task.result like e.g. isRated=true. However, there is a one return value within the task.result that looks like:
ReviewInfo{pendingIntent=PendingIntent{770540b: android.os.BinderProxy@ff152e8}, isNoOp=true}

The isNoOp is always true, but no idea what does this mean.
Do you have any experience with and could you please share some thought about this?
